# Debugging a C program using Structs

Tags: c, file, pointers, structure

I am attempting to write a program that sorts speed dating information for extra credit in my Computer Science 1 Course; And I am running into an odd problem. The program when it get's to a series of nested loops crashes after running the loop twice (At the point where the Debug Function is called). the function transferData; is only designed to take the data from a file and move it into the structures for later processing by a yet to be written function. I for the life of me can't figure it out so any advice would be very much welcome, below I've placed the code and below that the test data I am using.

```
caData transferData(fData * fileData, caData * workingData, int numCouples)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    workingData->maData = (struct mData*)malloc(sizeof(mData)*(numCouples*2));//Create Array of Match Data with cells equal to double the number of couples
    workingData->maData->couData = (struct cData*)malloc(sizeof(cData)*numCouples);//Create a Couple structure array with a number of cells equal to the number of couples.
    ///TODO:
    //Read in Names
    for(i = 0; i < (numCouples * 2); i++)//Rotate through Matches
    {
        if(i < numCouples)//Men First
        {
            debug();
            for(j = 0; j < numCouples; j++)//Scan in First half of Couples
            {
                for(k = 0; k < numCouples; k++)//Scan In Male Names
                {
                    fscanf(fileData->inputData, "%s", workingData->maData[i].couData[j].guyName);
                }

                for(k = 0; k < numCouples; k++)//Scan In Female Names
                {
                    fscanf(fileData->inputData, "%s", workingData->maData[i].couData[j].girlName);
                }
            }
        }
        else//Now the women
        {
           for(j = 0; j < numCouples; j++)//Scan in First half of Couples
            {
                for(k = 0; k < numCouples; k++)//Scan In Female Names
                {
                    fscanf(fileData->inputData, "%s", workingData->maData[i].couData[j].girlName);
                }

                for(k = 0; k < numCouples; k++)//Scan In male Names
                {
                    fscanf(fileData->inputData, "%s", workingData->maData[i].couData[j].guyName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //Read In Scores
    //Compute differances

}
```

EDIT: Condensed the code to the location of the error, it's where the debug function is called; it runs twice, then crashes. It's returning a -1073741819 (0xC0000005).

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: You need to 1. Tell us which line causes the crash, 2. Tell us the error message, and 3. boil this massive amount of code down to a small representative sample that exhibits the problem.

Comment: My apologies, I posted the entirety of the code in attempt to prevent confusion; I will attempt to reformat the above post.

Comment: Doesn't compile on visual studio for me... error C2027: use of undefined type 'main::caData'    If I were you I would not use typedef structs to define structs. C++ accepts struct foo {}; just fine.

Comment: @CJohnson OP is using C. In C, the typedefs are necessary.

Comment: @SigmusVictus that segment of code doesn't call any debug function.

Comment: My apologies again, It will be corrected.

Comment: I suspect you haven't allocated any space for the actual strings.

Comment: Within the nested structure, The strings are declared as guyName[256] and girlName[256]. Is this not correct?

Comment: Also, do NOT *damn* cast the *damn* return value of the *damn* malloc.

Comment: I suppose. You didn't show your structs. for each `k` you appear to simply store the name to the same location on each iteration.

Comment: @BrettHale I see, I think that maybe one of hte major issues thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf()` takes a `FILE*` argument, you have passed it an `fData*`.  Unless that is an alias for `FILE*` it won't do anything sensible, and if it is a type alias (typedef), why obfuscate it in that manner?

You are assigning elements of some structure passed to teh function.  Without showing what you are passing and the definition of the structure it is not possible to verify the correctness of the code shown, but the most common error when using `fscanf()` to assign a string is to overrun the buffer or not to have allocated a buffer in the first place.  In this case I would have to ask whether the `guyname` and `girlname` members are arrays of sufficient length.  It they are simply pointers, then you need to allocate space for the data.  You might also modify your format specifier to ensure that too long a string cannot be copies to these members.

If the caller is passing in `workingData` the it should be the caller's responsibility to allocate any necessary data.  It is bad practice to allocate dynamic memory locally and pass it back to a caller - it begs the question of where and when the memory will be free'd and is asking for a memory leek.

In the end the simplest, fastest and best way to debug this code is to step through it in a symbolic debugger.